# rails redirect in controller for a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have create method like this in rails controller:

```
def create
  @sale = Sale.new(sale_params)

  @sale.user_id = current_user.id  
  @sale.total = @sale.total_all

  params[:sale][:items_attributes].values.each do |p|
    @product = Product.find(p['product_id'])
    if @product.quantity.to_i - p['quantity'].to_i <= 0
      flash.now[:notice] = "Quantity is higher then stock"
    end
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @sale.save
      format.html { redirect_to @sale, notice: 'Sale was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @sale }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @sale.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

```
if @product.quantity.to_i - p['quantity'].to_i <= 0
  flash.now[:notice] = "Quantity is higher then stock"
end
```

this condition fails it means the controller redirected to create page itself otherwise it needs to redirect to index page. If I puts `render :new` in loop rails says error. How to do this?

Comment: This logic must be implemented in Product model as a validator and validation error must be returned.

Comment: Post the exact error you get.

Comment: Ok, single responsibility. Your controller DOESN'T have to know about your business rules. You should care about your product quantity in your Product  model as @HarshGupta said. Your controller just have to set the flash and redirect (or render). Using this controller "validation" you CAN have more products sold than your products quantity.

Answer (score 3):

You can move it to the model as Harsh suggested.  You'd do it something like this.  Then you can get rid of the loop.

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :items

  # Also make sure you validate children
  validates_associated :items

  validate :items_in_stock

  def items_in_stock
    items.each do |i|
      if i.quantity > i.product.quantity
        i.errors.add(:quantity) = "is not currently available"
      end
    end
  end

end
```